# Mercurial show diff against 2 parents or base during merge

Tags: merge, mercurial, dvcs, merge-conflict-resolution

Our teem recently faced with merge that removes one leaf of merge and we "lost" changes (as if you perform `hg merge --tool internal:local`).

This happen because we don't experienced with `hg merge` command.

`hg diff` shown only one difference, but not other.

```
BASE --- HEAD1 --- MERGE
   \---- HEAD2 --/
```

Suppose in *HEAD1* I merge *HEAD2* but has not yet commit changes.

*HEAD2* diff against *MERGE* I see by `hg diff`. It is `-r BASE:HEAD2` patch.

How can I see diff between current local merge state with *HEAD1* as if we merge from *HEAD2*

How can I see diff between current local merge state with *BASE*?

Comment: Please explain in detail the steps taken, I'm not entirely sure I follow what you did, in particular it sounds as though you merged two heads and had uncommitted local changes, is that right?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, before doing any code fixation I want compare current state against common ancestor and highlight hunks that relative to resolved conflit places, ignoring success merges (summary of all `.rej` files but with current source state).

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of this, but you can also do `hg diff -r HEAD1` to compare current state with HEAD1. Or `hg diff -r BASE` to compare current state with BASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Vince for suggestion. I reread `hg help diff` and `hg help revset` and get that I want.

Assume that you at *MERGE* before commit and perform merge from *HEAD1*.

To compare diff against *HEAD1* use one of:

```
hg diff
hg diff -r .
hg diff -r HEAD1
```

Check:

```
 hg log -r .
```

To compare diff against *HEAD1* use one of:

```
hg diff -r HEAD2
```

If you have only 2 heads in current branch last expression can be written without *HEAD2* name:

```
hg diff -r 'branch(.) & head() - .'
```

Check:

```
hg log -r 'branch(.) & head() - .'
```

To compare against *BASE*:

```
hg log -r 'ancestor(HEAD1, HEAD2)'
```

If you have only 2 heads in current branch last expression can be written without *HEAD1*/*HEAD2* names::

```
hg diff -r 'ancestor(branch(.) & head())'
```

Check:

```
hg log -r 'ancestor(branch(.) & head())'
```

I wander if there are any shortcut for second parent of current merge. For first - just dot sign...

**UPDATE** Hm... `p1()` and `p2()` are awesome! I rewrote my examples in way that they have no concrete names *HEAD1*/*HEAD2*:

```
hg diff -r 'p1()'
hg diff -r 'p2()'
hg diff -r 'ancestor(p1(), p2())'
```